# iPad not detecting touch while scrolling through HTML <select> list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

On page load, a timer starts, but is reset every time a touch event occurs. However, when I scroll through my `<select>` to view every `<option>`, the timer doesn't reset when I swipe to scroll down the list.

```
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 10000;

$('*').bind('touchstart mousemove keydown onscroll scroll touchmove touchend touchcancel touchleave touch', function () {
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    if (idleState == true) {}
    idleState = false;
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 
        location.reload();
    idleState = true; }, idleWait);
});
```

I've tried these as well:

`$('#the-list').bind(...)`

`$(document).bind(...)`

Does `<select>` require a different touch event? Since this is running on an iPad, is it possible that the native OS is wrapping the list in something I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

A few elements are simply out of our reach when talking about events and styling.

The select element is one of them. I think Apple wants to keep the behaviour of the select element consistent across the whole platform.

Another example is the keyboard. We still don't even have an event for monitoring the visibility of the keyboard.

Comment: I'm not trying to style it, I just want the iPad to recognize that it is in fact being touched while I'm scrolling through the list, forcing the timer to reset every time I swipe to scroll.

Comment: Yes, well it won't. Since none of your events will fire on any opened select box. Open the console and check this out: http://jsbin.com/wexasuxi/1/edit the "yeah buddy" console log is not firing when hovering over the opened select box.

Comment: What about detecting screen touch? So instead of looking for a finger swiping through the list, it just looks for a touch on the iPad, regardless of what underlying elements are being effected? I know very little about iPads, but is that a thing?

Comment: Sadly, thats impossible :( since you're literaly "leaving" the browser and entering the default select component of the operating system. But you could perhaps add the focus event to the list of events.

Comment: Let me ask you, what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need that timer? Maybe there's a different way..

Comment: The timer is for when the screen is idle (nobody touches it) for a set amount of time, the page gets reloaded to it's initial state.

Comment: Ah, ok.. Would anyone ever take more than 10 seconds to select something from a select box? Because i think if you would listen to the "change" event on every form you could say that that's a user interaction just like "mousedown" or "touchstart" is..

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't let you have on scroll events. They get qued and fired when the page finishes scrolling. Recently worked on a parralax project where this caused a big headache.